# Ubuntu 18.04 with Horizon Client 4.9 Scanner Crashes Client on Startup

Tags: 18.04, scanner

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Horizon Client 4.9 and a Fujitsu Scanner attached. Whenever the scanner is turned on the Client crashes. I've read that this is a known error because of the renaming of some file but i can't find any fixes. Anyone know of a fix for this?